# TFS Release CopyFiles task gives code EPERM

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm running latest version of TFS 2015 release manager. I have a simple release that includes a "CopyFiles" task. I need to have the "Clean Target Folder" option of the task enabled.

[image]

I have three target environments configured. Both are newly created identical Windows servers. The CopyFiles task works fine against the first two servers but for the next environment in the pipeline, when copying to the second server I get the following error:

```
2016-11-11T21:41:07.4324714Z found 2 files
2016-11-11T21:41:07.4324714Z ##[debug]file:D:/Build/_work/df9f2c4cf/(master) Orchard BTDF/drop/20161111.5.zip will be copied.
2016-11-11T21:41:07.4324714Z ##[debug]file:D:/Build/_work/df9f2c4cf/(master) Orchard BTDF/drop/Unzip.ps1 will be copied.
2016-11-11T21:41:07.4324714Z Cleaning target folder: \\Steatbt02\BizTalkDeployments2\Orchard
2016-11-11T21:41:07.4324714Z ##[debug]rm -rf \\Steatbt02\BizTalkDeployments2\Orchard
2016-11-11T21:41:07.4480915Z rm: could not remove directory (code EPERM): \\Steatbt02\BizTalkDeployments2\Orchard
2016-11-11T21:41:07.4480915Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
```

There's no sign of errors in the event log.

I created the share "\Steatbt02\BizTalkDeployments2" and granted "full-access" permissions to the account running the build agent. I even tried logging onto the build server and run as for the command prompt using the credentials of the build agent. From this command window I was able to remove the target folder 
"\Steatbt02\BizTalkDeployments2\Orchard" - so I can't think why the build agent would have trouble doing the same!

Any ideas what could be wrong, or what extra steps I could take to track down the root cause of the problem?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue. If the target folder is empty, will the error occur? Would you see the error if you create a new target folder?

Comment: EPERM error usually occurs then the operation is not permitted. Is there any file being used in the path during the deployment?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem was the agent queue selected for the problem environment.

Comment: Rob can you expand on what you mean by this answer? Just stating it was a problem doesn't go into what the problem actually was.

Comment: This was almost a year ago but my guess is I had selected the wrong queue.